# Avoid setUpClass to run every time for nose cherry picked tests

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

This is my tests class, in `mymodule.foo`:

```
class Some TestClass(TestCase):

  def setUpClass(cls):
    # Do the setup for my tests

  def test_Something(self)
    # Test something

  def test_AnotherThing(self)
    # Test another thing

  def test_DifferentStuff(self)
    # Test another thing
```

I'm running the tests from Python with the following lines:

```
tests_to_run = ['mymodule.foo:test_AnotherThing', 'mymodule.foo:test_DifferentStuff']
result = nose.run(defaultTest= tests_to_run)
```

(This is obviously a bit more complicated and there's some logic to pick what tests I want to run)

Nose will run just the selected tests, as expected, but the `setUpClass` will run once for every test in `tests_to_run`. Is there any way to avoid this?

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to run some dynamic set of tests while using `nose` in a Python script (not from the command line)

Comment: The *whole point* of `setUp` is that it runs every time. Perhaps you want [`setUpModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule) instead?

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned, [`setupModule`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupmodule-and-teardownmodule) is what I was after: it will run just once per the whole module where my tests reside.